# Crontab: read argument from file

Tags: python, bash, cron

I am trying to execute a python script (with chmod +x) which accepts several options via cronjob. One option is a password which I don't want to store in the crontab file, so I saved it with chmod 600 in my user's home directory (OS: raspbian).
My crobtab line is:

```
* * * * 5 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && /opt/scripts/myscript.py -p '$(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)'  >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1
```

The line

```
/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p '$(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)'  >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1
```

is executed correctly with bash, but not from the crontab. This is correct as crontab does not execute a bash - but how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not put in into `bash -c ".."`?

Comment: `/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p \`cat /home/pi/mypasswordfile\`  >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1`

or use `xargs`

Comment: Why not put the whole thing into a bash script file, and run that script from cron?

Comment: I used the suggestion of @RafaelAguilar and it worked like I wanted it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm gonna write it as an answer then! ;)

Comment: Another option would be to modify your script to read the password directly from a file, rather than having the shell feed the contents of the file to your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just capture your password and pass it as an argument using `cat` & backticks:

```
/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p `cat /home/pi/mypasswordfile` >> /tmp/backup.log
```

Disclosure: backticks  have been deprecated in favor of `$()` but sometimes just doesn't fit the scenario.

Comment: What keeps you from using `$(cat /home/pi/mypasswordfile)`?

Answer (score 3):

I generally recommend against putting any complex syntax directly into `crontab` files. Put it into a script, and run the script from `crontab`. So create a script like `runmyscript.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(date +%d) -le 7 ] 
then
    /opt/scripts/myscript.py -p "$(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)"
fi
```

and change the crontab to:

```
* * * * 5 /opt/scripts/runmyscript.sh >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes, I also follow this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to your `crontab` file, to use `bash` instead of `/bin/sh` to execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
bash -c '/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p $(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)'
```

Also, sometimes you might need to pass environmental variables, specially `DISPLAY` for some programs to run correctly, for example:

```
* * * * 5 env DISPLAY=:0 [ $(date +\%d) -le 07 ] && bash -c '/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p $(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)'  >> /tmp/backup.log 2>&1
```

Comment: You need to put the whole argument inside single quotes.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. I removed his single quotes, was that it? Can you please enlighten me?

Comment: Change your double quotes to single quotes. Otherwise, `$(...)` is seen by `/bin/sh`, and it doesn't like it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your comments, feedback is always appreciated. I know the difference between single and double quotes, but I fail to see why the usage above would be problematic. In my view, either single or double quotes on `bash -c "/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p $(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)"` would work fine, would it not?

Comment: No, because when you put it in double quotes, the `$` is processed by the original shell, not the shell run by `bash -c`.

Comment: But in single quotes the `$(...)` will not expand, right? I just tried `var=hi; bash -c 'echo $var'` and the `var` did not expand.

Comment: Try: `bash -c 'var=foo; echo $var'`.

Comment: Or `export var=hi; bash -c 'echo $var'`.

Comment: You didn't export the variable, so it doesn't exist in the new shell.

Comment: Correct. Thank you for all the explanations, I changed my answer. The point using double quotes in this case would expand the `$` on the original shell rather than on the targeted `bash -c` shell is an insight I missed. Many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem. Quoting can get very complicated when you have nested shell invocations like this. That's why I try to avoid it, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I follow the same approach as your answer (and thus I upvoted it), but I tried to answer here in the same style as the OP crafted it (maybe I shouldn't, that's why I made this oversight). Just one more question if you can indulge me: in this context, would `bash -c '/opt/scripts/myscript.py -p "$(< /home/pi/mypasswordfile)"'` be ok or would the `$(...)` part be picked up by the original shell?